# Django-Haystack: Preparing index data that has choices

Tags: django, django-haystack, faceted-search, facet

Good afternoon,

Say I have a models.py like so:

```
class my_stackoverflow_question(models.Model):
    feedback_choices = (
        (GREAT, "Was a great question"),
        (MEH, "Could've figured it out"),
        (TERRIBLE, "I pity the foo"),
    )

    feedback = models.IntegerField(default=GREAT, choices=feedback_choices)
```

My search_indexes.py is such:

```
class question_index(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = ...stuff...
    feedback = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='feedback', faceted=True)
```

When I display the above facet, the integer value will show through the template

```
{% for feed in facets.fields.feedback %}
    {{feed.0}} - {{feed.1}}
{% endfor %}

# Shows: 0-999
#        1-1
#        2-0 ;)
```

I'd like feed.0 to display the actual choice value, like obj.get_feedback_display() would. So I thought I'd try to prepare the data before indexing:

```
def prepare_feedback(self, obj):
    return obj.feedback.get_feedback_display()  #'AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'get_feedback_display''
```

or
    return "%s" % (obj.feedback.get_feedback_display()) #Same error as above

I'd even be fine if the data was indexed as an integer and then the feed.0 facet displayed the name -- but I believe the facet fields come straight from the index and not the model (is this correct?)

How can I display the facet's display_name as opposed to it's raw value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with indexing the display text instead of the integer choice value. You need to tell haystack that it should expect a string instead of a long for feedback, and then call get_feedback_display() on the `my_stackoverflow_question` object itself, not the feedback field.

So:

```
class question_index(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = ...stuff...
    feedback = indexes.CharField(model_attr='feedback', faceted=True)

    def prepare_feedback(self, obj):
        return obj.get_feedback_display()
```